# Can't click on fragment link or scroll on my page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm working on a school assignment where I have to make a web page that states what I like and I talk about some of those subjects (I'd like to note that it's only basic HTML, all the stuff I'm doing with CSS is extra).

The thing is, on my web page I put a bunch of line breaks to test my fragment link, and not only did the fragment link not work but for some reason, I couldn't even use my mouse's scroll wheel to scroll down to it. Here's the code (aside from the title, first head tag, and first HTML tag)

```css
body {
  background-color: #dadced;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  width: 75%;
}

p,
h1,
h2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7b967f;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7b967f
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

h2.link {
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#game-txt {
  background-color: #e5d3c3;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#comp-txt {
  background-color: #e4e58b border-radius: 25px;
}

#film-txt {
  background-color: #ef9e9e;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

div#gif {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 25;
}

div#gcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  padding-left: 250px;
}

div#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 146px;
  padding-bottom: 50;
}

div#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 546px;
  padding-bottom: 50;
}

div#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 932px;
  padding-bottom: 50;
}
```

```html
<div id=gcontainer>
  <div id=gif>
    <img src="chapter select gif/Chapter_select.gif" alt="chapter select 
    sign" width="800" height="500">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=img1>
  <img class=img-circle src="Game.png" alt="Game Banner" width="130" height="131">
  <h2><a href="#game">1. Games</a></h2>
</div>
<div id=img2>
  <img class=img-circle src=computer.png alt="Picture of a CPU with 
    glowing blue light" width="130" height="131">
  <h2 class=link>2. Computers</h2>
</div>
<div id=img3>
  <img class=img-circle src="Film making.png" alt="Picture of film" width="130" height="131">
  <h2 class=link>3. Film Making</h2>
</div>
<h2><a name="game" /> Games</h>
```

Comment: Can you post full html, seems the css `div#img1 {` is missing the close brace `}`?

Comment: The missing close brace in `div#img1` was a typo when I was posting the question, I guess I missed that when proof-reading.

Comment: You have multiple issues. 1. Wrap all attribute values with double quotes `"` like `<div id="gcontainer">`. 2. image `src` value should not have space as in `src="chapter select gif..."`. 3. For the fragment links to work, you should have elements with matching `id` attribute and not `name` attribute. For an instance, for `href="#game"` you should have an element with `id="game"`. Points `1` & `2` are best practices to avoid any unexpected issues. But point# `3` is mandatory one to follow.

Comment: Okay, thanks EDIT: it works now :)

Comment: Where are the fragment links? I cannot find any anchor tag in your code.

Comment: I was using the name instead of the id attribute, I was misinformed about what to use for anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

- This HTML is broken `<h2><a name="game" /> Games</h>` - it starts with `H2`, ends with `H`. You have an incorrect self closing anchor tag without the required `href`. I'm not even sure you'd want an anchor tag there - it should probably just be an H2.
- You used `name="game"` and perhaps once upon a time that was correct but now in HTML5 it's supposed to be `id="game"`

Change your HTML to something like `<h2 id="game">Games</h2>`

Then you will be able to link to it via a `<a href="#game">Link to Games</a>`